Integration by parts to switch sign on anti-Hermitian Louivillian
I am self studying non-equilibrium stat mech and a common theme is that I am unable to reproduce the "this follow from integration by parts" parts of derivations. Here is the most recent:
In equilibrium, take an expectation value of particle position $r(t)$ at time $t$ over an arbitrary distribution $f(\vec{x},t)$ where the Louivillian generates the time evolution of such a distribution. We define the Louivillian as $\mathcal{L} = \dot{x} \cdot \nabla_x = \sum_{i}^{N} \left ( \vec{\dot{p}_i} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial{\vec{p}_i}} + \vec{\dot{r}}_i \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial{\vec{r}_i}}\right )$:
\begin{align*}
\langle r(t) \rangle &= \int d \vec{x} f(\vec{x},t) r(0)\\
&= \int d \vec{x} e^{-\mathcal{L}t}f(\vec{x},0) r(0)\\
&= \int d \vec{x} f(\vec{x},0) e^{\mathcal{L}t} r(0)\\
&= \int d \vec{x} f(\vec{x},0) r(t)\\
\end{align*}
Step $2 \rightarrow 3$ is explained as "where in the second line we have inserted the Liouvillian. Because the Liouvillian is anti-Hermitian, we can switch its order of evaluation from left to right at the cost of an overall negative sign in the argument of exponential - effectively reversing the sign of the time. This follows from integration by parts."
I am totally unable to reproduce this step $2 \rightarrow 3$ of switching the sign on the Louivillian and moving it past the distribution $f(\vec{x},0)$. Could someone please provide an idea? :-) A general commentary on this idea of integration by parts to switch the sign on an anti-Hermitian operator would also be appreciated!

In your definition of the Liouvillian operator, an imaginary unit is missing.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I have seen the Liouvillian defined both with and without the factor of i. Given they expect it to be anti-Hermitian, this looks correct to me

@BySymmetry Certainly, it can be defined with or without including the factor I, but if it is absorbed in the definition of $\cal L$, it should appear elsewhere. In particular, in the explicit definition of the operator in terms of the Poisson bracket.

You are unable to reproduce this step for the pure and simple reason that the advection operator ($\mathcal{L}$ is nothing else than a multidimentional advection operator) is not skew-symmetric (cf. e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advection#Treatment_of_the_advection_operator_in_the_incompressible_Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations).
